# Delete array element by clicking button in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am trying to make a delete button in HTML to delete an element in array, but why is it not working?

```
 <script>
        function rem(value){
         todolist.splice(i,0);
        }    
 </script>
.
.
.
<% for(var i=0; i <todolist.length; i++){ %>
                <lt> <%= todolist[i].name %></lt>
                <button onclick = "rem(i)">x</button><br>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Change todolist.splice(i,0) to todolist.splice(i,1). From a quick look at your snippet, you should be right after that.

Answer (score 0):

Splice function's second argument defines how many elements you want to delete. Here in your code you have passed 0.

```
todolist.splice(i,0);
```

Please try using something like this.

```
todolist.splice(i,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

first argument of splice method is defined the index of array and second argument is defined how many elements you want to delete from array. 
If you are using

```
todolist.splice(i, 0);
```

that means you are deleting 0 element so if you want to delete 1 element then you have to use below code

```
todolist.splice(i, 1);
```

Comment: You should ```<button onclick="rem(<%= i %>)">x</button>``` instead of ```<button onclick="rem(i)">x</button>```  in index.ejs file. Then you can access the current index. then you should create a delete api in app.js and call from index.ejs.